# Is it possible to buffer the output of $app->run from silex?

Tags: silex

I was wondering if it is possible to store the output created by silex. What I want to achieve is something like this :

```
<?php
    require('core.php');
    $out = $app->run();
    echo $app['twig']->render('header.html');
    echo $out;
    echo $app['twig']->render('footer.html');
```

I'd like to do it this way because some of the navigation is build inside my dynamic controllers and registered as a global into twig. I've tried to use the out buffering [ob_start](http://be1.php.net/ob_start) mechanism without succes :

```
<?php
    require('core.php');
    ob_start();
    $app->run();
    $out = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $app['twig']->render('header.html');
    echo $out;
    echo $app['twig']->render('footer.html');
```

Any other ideas on this subject ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a split of header/main/footer and using the global variables, you should use an unique template with template inheritence.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#template-inheritance

Comment: This is true. I should swap out my MiddleWare with this mechanic and move my menu build up to a custom [Twig_SimpleFunction](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)